# Excel - how to count number of times a worker has either accepted work, rejected work, or not answered

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an example dataset with columns **"Worker", "Accepted work", "Rejected work", and "Did not answer"** (see picture 1 - [Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvwoN.png)). The true dataset includes hundreds of rows. Each row includes the name of a worker in the Worker column, and either a date or a random string which indicates that the worker has either accepted work, rejected work, or did not answer at all.

My objective is to count the number of times a worker has accepted work, rejected work, or not answered in a summary table (see picture 2 - [Summary table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nGpe.png)). I suppose the function needs to match the name of a worker between the dataset and the summary table, and then count the worker-specific count row by row (accept count, reject count, or no-answer count). I struggled to find a function that returns worker-specific counts, but did not manage to find any. For example, xlookup can match names, but return only one value. Do you have ideas?

Thanks for your aid in advance!

Comment: Hi. Please don't add _"SOLVED"_ or similar markers to the question title. Questions with accepted answers are marked as solved with a green box next to them. I've rolled back your last edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the sample about your problem, you can use **SUMPRODUCT** to get your result:

**=SUMPRODUCT(($A2=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$14)*(Sheet1!B$2:B$14<>""))**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let assume that your dataset is range is `A1:D14` and the summary range is `A18:D26`. On B19, enter the formula:

```
=COUNT(IF(FILTER($B$2:$B$14,$A$2:$A$14=A19)>0,1,""))
```

On C19, enter the formula:

```
=COUNT(IF(FILTER($C$2:$C$14,$A$2:$A$14=A19)>0,1,""))
```

On D19, enter the formula:

```
=COUNT(IF(FILTER($D$2:$D$14,$A$2:$A$14=A19)>0,1,""))
```

Drag the formulae down to fill the other cells.

**Explanation:** The `Filter` function returns the cells related to the worker for each criteria. It returns 0 when there is no data. That's why the `IF` function is used to check if the cell does not contains 0. Then, only cells that don't have zeros are counted.

[image: IMG:]